# Missing artifact com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:1.9.11

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I build a maven project and get an error on pom.xml Missing artifact in some dependencies. How can I resolve it?

[image]

Comment: Your IDE is warning you about the dependency, is your XML valid? Whats the red for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot see the value of `${jackson.version}` on your image, but from the title of the question I assume it's version 1.9.11 you're looking for. If you check in any of the multiple maven repository viewers, like [maven central](http://search.maven.org/), you'll see that version is not present, and therefore maven cannot resolve that dependency. Click this link to see the versions available in [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.fasterxml.jackson.core%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jackson-core%22).

You must choose an existing version from the central repository or, if you have version 1.9.11 in another repository, include that repository details in your pom.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify property of the jackson.version and this can be done by adding the section shown below:

```
<properties>
<jackson.version>2.10.0</jackson.version>
</properties>
```

The version has been updated as per the recent documentation from Maven.

Answer (score 1):

From the Two Maven Dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.2</version>
        <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.2.2</version>
        <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>
```

Remove the bundle tag from both the dependencies and keep the version almost same it will work else it will show the above mentioned error.